# Deduplicating Values in Excel and Adding Results Together

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a very large excel spreadsheet containing application names in one column, and counts for each application in the next column. I have gone through the spreadsheet and removed all of the versions for each application, so only the application names remain. However, I now need to find a way to deduplicate all of the application names, and then count the values in the next column. See below for a quick example:

Google Chrome - 7

Google Chrome - 10

Google Chrome - 5

What I need to do here is deduplicate those Google Chrome results, but then count the numbers on the right. So ideally, the result would be:

Google Chrome - 22

However, I need to be able to apply this Excel formula to all rows, regardless of the application name. In addition, I am unable to download 3rd party Excel plugins or add-ons. Does anybody know a formula that I can apply to all of the cells so that I can get the results that I am looking for?

Any information or advice is hugely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: SUMIFS should be helpful. Or use a pivot table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a formula like:

```
=SUMIFS($B$1:$B$25,$A$1:$A$25,A1)
```

where B is the column with the number of instances and A is the browser type

Comment: Thank you David! This is tremendously helpful.